# ImageMagick - get all color values in separate arrays

Tags: bash, imagemagick

I need to get all R,G,B values for each pixel in separate arrays.

This command:

```
convert image.png -depth 8 txt:
```

outputs multiple lines like this:

```
277,533: (158,167,146)  #9EA792  srgb(158,167,146)
```

I could separate the values of one line:

```
R_pixel=$(echo $test | cut -d "(" -f2 | cut -d "," -f1)
G_pixel=$(echo $test | cut -d "," -f3 | cut -d "," -f2)
B_pixel=$(echo $test | cut -d "," -f4 | cut -d ")" -f1)
```

Which gets me 158 for R_pixel, but not for all lines.

But there has to be a better way, possibly directly from ImageMagick, right?

This does not get their correct values for R, as it doesn't matter which channel I choose:

```
R_pixel_array=( $( convert image.png -format "%[fx:r]" -compress none  PGM:-) )
```

In the end, I need an R_array, which contains only R values for each pixel.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do ultimately, please? This approach is horribly inefficient and there may be much faster/simpler ways to achieve your goal. Thank you.

Comment: please update the question with a) multiple lines of input and b) the expected results/arrays (corresponding to the sample input)

Comment: As you didn't reply to my question, nor give any indication that you were seeking an efficient implementation for larger images - which nobody would expect anyone to want to store in `bash` arrays - I gave you a simple solution. As I now know from your comments that you want a fast solution, I have updated my answer to that end. Please have another look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close. Would you please try the following:

```
R_pixel_array=( $(convert image.png -depth 8 -channel R -separate -compress none PGM:- | awk '!/^#/&&++c>=4') )
```

- The `-channel R` and `-separate` options extract the red channel only.
- The `PGM:` prefix converts to a gray scale (one channel per pixel) image.
- The `awk '!/^#/&&++c>=4'` command skips the header lines.

Comment: Both suggestions work, but your solution is much more efficient. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Answer**

As you appear to want an efficient answer, please try the following. It runs in around 20% of the time needed for the `awk` solution. The first 4 parameters just generate a large test image:

```
magick -size 4000x3000 xc:red -depth 8 -channel r -separate gray: | od -t u1 -An
```

**Original Answer**

Make a 4x3 starting image for testing:

```
magick -size 4x3 gradient:red-blue start.png
```

**Enlarged**

[image]

```
magick start.png -channel r -separate -crop 1x1 -format "%[fx:int(p{0,0}*255)]\n" info: 
255
255
255
255
127
127
127
127
0
0
0
0
```